# PHP form and database to .FNM 3.2 file format

Tags: php

I have a PHP form and databse. Once form is submitted it fills a database. The database can be search and then it can generate a .fnm file which is a fannie mae 3.2... Once file is downloaded I try to import but file has error. Code Below. Fake info of course

```
EH       business               123456789
TH T100099-002     2000
TPI 1.0001                              N
0001  3.20                                                                                                                           237500.00  4.00036005                                                                                                                                                                
02A123 TBD                                           
20152015DecDecThuThu        
10000       
TBD                   :     
00A-020/  4/N  :Other Income or Assets Used                   :33       
02A-020/  4/N  :Property Street Address                       :St. steven street        
02A-040/ 74/N  :Property State                                :California       
02A-050/ 76/N  :Property Zip Code                             :90045        
02B-030/ 87/C  :Is this a purchase or refinance?              :16&gt;       
03A-030/  6/C  :Applicant Social Security Number              :134-71-1112      
03A-040/ 15/Y  :Applicant First Name                          :John         
03A-050/ 50/N  :Applicant Middle Name                         :steve        
03A-060/ 85/Y  :Applicant Last Name                           :doe      
03A-160/124/N  :Email                                         :johndoe@yopmail.com              
03A-080/124/N  :Home Phone                                    :331-212-1312                 
03A-090/134/N  :Age                                           :25       
03A-110/139/N  :Marital Status                                :U        
03C-040/ 15/C  :Residence Street Address                      :St. steven street        
03C-060/ 85/C  :Residence State                               :California       
03C-070/ 87/C  :Residence Zip Code                            :90045        
03C-090/ 96/N  :Own/Rent/Living Rent Free                     :Rent     
03C-100/ 97/N  :No. Yrs.                                      :Greater then two years           
06C-030/ 97/N  :Checking Amount                               :22       
06C-030/ 97/N  :Saving Amount                                 :22       
08A-090/ 13/N  :Do you pay child support or alimony?          :No   
04A-030/ 13/N  :Employer Name                                 :Self-Employed            
04A-090/129/N  :Self Employed                                 : Y           
04A-100/130/N  :Yrs. on this job                              :0        
04A-110/132/N  :Months on this job                            :0        
GOE-070/140/N  :First Time Home Buyer?                        :Yes  
00070 3.20                                                   
00011 3.20 
LNC1 01                 N                                N2015112520160101                 
PID                                                  
PCH    01    
TT      2000
ET 123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

The FNM file is a space deliminator file. Meaning you have x fields with y columns on each row. Each column has a defined amount of space. For example, a field might call for 35 space. If your value of the field is only 20 then you need to pad the remaining by 15 spaces. Depending on how many fields you include in this file the process can take a while.

I just did this for a customer of mine and I was able to generate a FNM file to import into there Point software.

You will need the magic decoder ring that your mortgage guy should be able to get from Fanie Mae. It is not a public document.

Comment: here is an example generated from PHP:

Comment: I need help with similar kind of task, can you help?